# Android: oAuth авторизация приложения на сервере

Tags: oauth, android, java

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с одним моментов в алгоритме oAuth 2.0 для приложений. В статье [`"Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps"`](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) есть момент, 
который мне непонятен совсем:

> To get your app’s cert signature, use the following shell command:

```
     $ keytool -exportcert -alias <your-key-name> -keystore <your-key-store-file> -v -list
```

> Copy the octets labeled “SHA1”, paste them into the Developer Console field, and create your app’s Client ID. Once again, all you’ll really need from the readout is the Client-ID string.

Куда ввести эту команду? В какую командную строку? Где взять `<your-key-store-file>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. cmd.exe, если под маком то - терминал
2. смотри пункт 1
3. your-key-store-name - путь к файлу, в котором будут хранится все ключи, необходимые для подписи релиз версий приложений. в твоем случае, если речь идет об одном приложении, то там будет 1 ключ. если у тебя нет этого файла, то нужно его создать. это можно сделать как из командной строки, так и через эклипс например.

Comment: Так эта утилита создаст мне SHA1 только для имени приложения?

Comment: нет. она даст отпечаток вашего ключа, которым вы подписываете приложение.

Comment: очень важный момент при работе с SHA1  - если пишите на IntellJIDEA возможно придется заново получать debug.keystore (androidstudio скорее всего тоже этот баг не профиксила) более подробно в комментарии @aldem67  http://hashcode.ru/questions/275098/google-maps-api-v2-google-maps-android-api-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87

Answer (score 0):

Здесь есть хорошая статья на эту тему:

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/221-urok-123-kak-podpisat-prilozhenie-utility-keytool-i-jarsigner.html